# Is iron ruby on Silverlight a viable alternative to C#?

Tags: c#, ruby, silverlight

I've heard a lot of buzz about the Iron languages..

I mostly write line of business applications in c# and I'm not really enjoying c# these days.

Is IronRuby mature and fast enough to be used in silverlight right now?

As in am I gonna get a call in the middle of the night from an angry customer cause the silverlight app they depend on is buggy / grindingly slow?

Comment: Yes, you probably will -- which is to say, C# and IronRuby are precisely equivalent in this respect. :-)

Comment: If you mean to say, C# exhibits poor performance, I don't agree with that.

Comment: Note that Microsoft appears to have lost interest in Iron*.

Comment: @Cheeso: I think Jerry's point was that you can expect to get calls from angry customers regardless of your implementation language.  Some customers are just like that.

Answer (score 1):

Compared to C# I don't have any comparison data but in general IronRuby is known to be overall slower than native ruby.

Maturity wise, I'd say it's not either. It still doesn't support 100% of the ruby language feature set and getting IronRuby running w/ silverlight does require a few more steps then just using C#.

I would say stay with c# for your silverlight needs unless there is some business need that makes the choice of ruby a requirement.

Comment: Agreed.  I think you would be going pretty hard against the grain to get things working with IronRuby.  For example, if you are going to use codegen features such as with WCF RIA Services or Self-tracking entities in EF, I doubt they will codegen IronRuby for you.

Answer (score 1):

And most importantly, as far as I know, IronRuby + Visual Studio doesn't compile down to exe / dll so you'll have to give out your source code within your application.

I don't know if things changed recently, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

The last time I looked at IronRuby (6-7 months ago), it didn't integrate with Visual Studio, which was a deal-killer for me.  I can live without syntax coloring and auto-complete, but I can't live without at least some degree of debugger support.

Comment: Touche.. There is now support via some tools by msoft